# Why I am getting compilation error here if I use unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, std, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am pretty new to C++.
I am trying to add unique pointer of parent class in derived (Child) class.
Getting error : error: 'virtual Iparent::~Iparent()' is protected within this context

As per my understanding I can access protected member (In this case destructor) in child class, still why I am getting this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class Iparent
{
    protected:
        Iparent()
        {
        }
        virtual ~Iparent()
        {
        }
    
    public:
        virtual void print() = 0;
    
};
class child : public Iparent
{
    public:
    unique_ptr<Iparent> obj;
    void print()
    {
    }
    child(unique_ptr<Iparent> obj) : obj(move(obj))
    {
    }
    ~child()
    { 
    }
};
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: But `unique_ptr` is not a child class of `IParent`. The destructor is being called from within the `unique_ptr` class not from within the `child` class.

Comment: A `std::unique_ptr<T>` is responsible for destructing its `T`.  You are being told that `std::unique_ptr<Iparent>` is forbidden from accessing that `~Iparent()`.

Comment: @john Same should happen in case of shared_ptr right? When I replace unique_ptr with shared_ptr, compiler is not complaining

Comment: @KrishnaPadia It depends on how the destructor is being called. If its called from a `child` object then the protected destructor is ok, but it's called from an `Iparent` pointer then it is not OK. In my implementation of the standard library `shared_ptr` does the former but `unique_ptr` does the latter. So your code is OK with `shared_ptr` but not `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is much more complex, and relies on several layers of templates and type erasure to provide its specified function. You cannot surmise how `unique_ptr` should behave just by seeing the way `shared_ptr` is working.

Comment: @john I wonder whether it is guaranteed by the standard that `delete` will be called on a pointer of type `child`. According to http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.dest#1.3 and http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.const#6.sentence-1, it seemingly is, but I am not sure about this.